# Where can I find the shower faucet stem replacement and do I have to break the wall to replace it?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

It is somewhat working but the water flow is not as big as before. When I turned it to get more water the water instead would get smaller until it is fully stopped.

[image]

Comment: Can you get to the other side of the wall ?

Comment: The stem will come out without breaking the wall. of course you will need to shut off the water before you unscrew the valve assembly from the valve body. There is a special socket wrench to remove the valve stem.

Comment: See this https://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-Shower-Valve-Socket-Wrench-16PL0135/304217587

Answer (score 5):

Beyond the threads, (to the left of the threads in the pic), there are flats that indicate it can be turned to get the stem out.

Use a deep socket or an open end wrench (or, if it's all you have, an adjustable wrench) and turn counter clock-wise.

The seal at the end of the stem may need to be replaced. There may be debris in the seat or damage. It all will be revealed when the stem is out.

Answer (score 4):

Before you take the stem out.

After many years of usage the rotational stop has moved out of position, as indicated by

> When I turned it to get more water the water instead would get smaller until it is fully stopped.

Check the inside of the knob to see the stop setting and if it is adjustable.

There is a second hint, as a black ring with flat surface part over the valve rod. Try to adjust it.

[image: ring]